# Searching through a partially sorted array in O(lgn)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search

I'm having a hard time solving this problem.

```
A[1..n] is an array of real numbers which is partially sorted:
There are some p,q  (1 <= p <= q <=n) so:
A[1] <= ... <= A[p]
A[p] >= ... >= A[q]
A[q] <= ... <= A[n]

How can we find a value in this array in O(lgn)?
(You can assume that the value exists in the array)
```

Comment: Your problem is similar to searching in an array that is increasing and then decreasing. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17351325/56778 might be helpful.

Comment: @JimMischel This is a very different problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make 3 binary searches: from 1 to p, p to q and q to n. The complexity is still O(logn).

**Since we don't know p and q:**

You cannot solve this problem in logn time. Assume a case where you have a sorted list of positive numbers with one zero mixed in (p+1=q and A[q]=0). This situation satisfies all the criteria you mentioned. Now, the problem of finding where that zero is located cannot be solved in sub O(n) time. Therefore your problem cannot be solved in O(logn) time.

Comment: without knowing p and q. It's impossible to find in O(log n). Worst case will be O(n). so you can't rely on any implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the "buried zero" worst case already pointed out, I would still recommend implementing an algorithm that can often speed things up, depending on p,q.  For example, suppose that you have n numbers, and each increasing and decreasing region has size at least k.  Then if you check 2^m elements in your array, including the first and last element and the rest of the elements as equally spaced as possible, starting with m=2 and then iteratively increasing m by 1, eventually you will reach m when you find 3 pairs of  consecutive elements (A,B),(C,D),(E,F) from left-to-right out of the 2^m elements that you have checked, which satisfy A < B,  C > D, E < F (some pairs may share elements).  If my back-of-the-envelope calculation is correct, then the worst-case m you will need to achieve this will have you checking no more than 4n/k elements, so e.g. if k=100 you are much faster than checking all n elements. Then you know everything before A and everything after F are increasing sequences, and you can binary search through them.  Now, if m got big enough that you checked at least sqrt(n) elements, then you can finish up by doing a brute-force search between A and F and the overall running time will be O(n/k + sqrt(n)).  On the other hand, if the final m had you check fewer than sqrt(n) elements, then you can further increase m until you have checked sqrt(n) elements.  Then there will be 2 pairs of consecutive checked elements (A,B),(C,D) that satisfy A < B, C > D, and there will also be 2 pairs of consecutive checked elements (W,X),(Y,Z) later in the array that satisfy W > X, Y < Z.  Then everything before A is increasing, everything between D and W is decreasing, and everything after Z is increasing.  So you can binary search these 3 regions in the array.  The remaining part of the array that you haven't entirely searched through has size O(sqrt(n)), so you can use brute-force search the unchecked regions and the overall running time is O(sqrt(n)).  Thus the bound O(n/k + sqrt(n)) holds in general.  I have a feeling this is worst-case optimal, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Note that for this solution to work, you need to first scan through the array and collapse consecutive sequences of duplicate values by representing them as just one value (and you can record the number or range of indices that have this value).  I.e., you need O(n) pre-processing to make searches achieve the O(n/k + sqrt(n)) running time.  Otherwise, e.g. if you have an array of all 1's except for one hidden zero, the solution won't work as fast -- you'll have to check all elements in the worst case.

Comment: Or, since you don't know p and q and presumably don't have time to find p and q, then you need to assume that consecutive sequences of duplicates have length O(1).

Answer (score 0):

It's solvable in O(log<sup>2</sup>n).

1. if at midpoint the slope is decreasing we're in the `p..q` range.
2. if at midpoint the slope is increasing, we're either in `1..p` or in `q..n` range.

   - perform a binary search in `1.. mid point` and `mid point..n` ranges to seek for a value where the slope is decreasing. It will be found only in one of the ranges. Now we know in which of the `1..p` and `q..n` subranges the mid point is located.
3. repeat the process from (1) for the subrange with the peaks until hitting the `p..q` range.
4. find the peaks in the subranges by applying algorithm in  [Divide and conquer algorithm applied in finding a peak in an array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887279/divide-and-conquer-algorithm-applied-in-finding-a-peak-in-an-array)
5. perform 3 binary searches in the ranges 1..p, p..q, q..n.

==> Overall complexity is O(log<sup>2</sup>n).

Comment: If there is one peak, the solution you mentioned works. If there is a peak and a bottom it might not. You say "easily extended" could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ElKamina I've elaborated - find one peak (let's say it's `p`) and search in the subranges `1..p`, `p..n` to find the second one. What is "bottom"?

Comment: How do you find one peak? In that answer you pick a 'mid' and see if it is increasing or decreasing at the 'mid'. If it is increasing you set new 'start' to 'mid'. Otherwise 'end' to 'mid'. And recursively check. Here you cannot do the same. If it is increasing at the mid you cannot be sure that peak is after mid and so on.

Comment: This solution doesn't work, look at the counter-example in one of the answers.  It's possible that the entire array is increasing positive except for one zero buried somewhere in the array.  If you find 2 peaks, you'll just get the last two elements in the array (assuming the zero is not there) and you'll have no information about where the zero is.  I think at the very least you are going to need some heavy assumptions to make something like you proposed work.

Comment: @ElKamina That's correct. In this case the condition should be the decrease, not increase - this will ensure that the currently checked value is in the `p..q` range. I agree that the algorithm should be adapted a bit - find the decrease at first and apply the original algorithm after that for the 2 subranges

Comment: @icepack When you apply it to two ranges how can you make sure your algorithm is still O(logn). You say that algorithm needs to be modified and by now I hope I have convinced you that that modification is not obvious or simple. If you could elaborate your modification, that would clear out lot of things.

Comment: @ElKamina I stand corrected, updated the solution. Indeed, O(logn) seems ambitious but O(log^2(n)) is achievable - still better than O(n)

Comment: @icepack Good solution! In practice may work at sub O(n) complexity. But in theory it is still O(n). If the length of range p..q is very small. you will end up reading almost all of the array.

Comment: @ElKamina Why is that? There is no dependency in the algorithm on the `p..q` range size.

Comment: @icepack In the worst case (i.e. when you cannot find a point that satisfies step 1 (i.e. midpoint is decreasing), you will be making two branches all the time, until the very last moment. This is not exactly O(log^2 n)